# TPS560200 - Output voltage wrong

Tags: power-supply

One of the students at my uni has laid out a PCB with a [TPS560200](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps560200.pdf) step-down converter. However, instead of 5V it only outputs 0.9V. I've checked the feedback resistors and they are correct*. The problem happens on multiple boards.

My initial guess was that the layout is wrong. Suggested layout is:

[image]

And this is what was produced:

[image]

My guess is that the output inductor is too far away. Would this be the likely cause? What else should I suggest to change or troubleshoot?

**Update***

It turns out the feedback resistors were all swapped.

Comment: The fact that the high power switching track is right next to the high impedance track may be the issue, ideally keep the lower feedback resistor close to the feedback pin and keep the switching stuff well away from it. I'd try and spin the chip around 180, that way the switching pin goes straight into the inductor, the feedback track can be long provided it's kept away from any sources of noise.

Comment: @Tom That sounds reasonable. I'll have a look on the scope.

Comment: The input cap should be as close as possible to the VIN pin. The feedback resistors should tap directly off the output cap, not the inductor. The grounds of the input cap, output cap, and IC chip should all be as close together as possible.

Comment: The trace going to VIN should pass through the input cap. The cap shouldn't be off on another branch by itself.

Comment: It's hard to tell with such a small photo, but it looks like the ground that is connected to U2's GND pin is an island (probably not, but worth checking - I can't see under the chip).

Comment: Thanks for looking. It turns out I was wrong, there is a problem with the divider - the resistors were swapped. @DanLaks thanks for your comments on layout.

Comment: Good that fixing the feedback network helps. However, as noted, don't trust the layout produced by the student. It deviates very far from the recommended layout in many of the ways that cause poor results from a switching power supply. In the next revision, definitely improve the layout of this portion of the board.